# Cleaned text has significantly worse classification accuracy?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, nlp, classification, spacy

I'm trying to classify whether or not I liked books that I've read this year based on the text in the books. I'm using the preprocessing described [here](https://www.dataquest.io/blog/tutorial-text-classification-in-python-using-spacy/), and a variety of sklearn classification models.

At first I was just feeding the models the raw text, but I cleaned it based on GloVe embeddings (a process described [here](https://www.kaggle.com/christofhenkel/how-to-preprocessing-when-using-embeddings)). The text was improved from 40% vocab, 80% coverage to 80% vocab, 98% coverage based on GloVe embeddings. However, for some reason, after cleaning the text, the accuracy of the classification models seemed to be the same or lower.

Uncleaned text model results:
[image: Uncleaned text model results]

Cleaned text model results:
[image: Cleaned text model results]

One thing to note is that the classes are quite imbalanced (75% of books were good as compared to 25% bad), so accuracy above 75% should be expected, since 75% is what the model would get if it guessed good every single time.

I've linked my full notebook [here](https://deepnote.com/project/c3a30d34-9496-46b5-acca-29c0a25aa9a0) so you can check out the specific code if that will be helpful for solving this issue. I'm incredibly confused; I can't see where I'm going wrong, but it can't be right that cleaning the text data has zero or negative impact on model accuracy.

Comment: (1) for imbalanced classification to see if your classifier has any value either compare against baseline (random guessing) or use ROC AUC  as the metric (2) whether your preproc adds value to your modelling pipeline should be checked via CV. (3) Cleaning text might be useful for BOW models, especially for smaller datasets, because it reduces dimensionality, but as you see it reduces model accuracy for word embeddings, because you're loosing valuable info.

Comment: (1) I'll look into using ROC AUC. (2) could you expand on this? How would I check whether it adds value through CV? (3) to clarify, cleaning text solely consists of expanding contractions, lowercasing, splitting with punctuation, and getting rid of curly quotes as compared to straight quotes (which makes the same contraction appear different to the model), so I don't see how the model is losing info there.

Answer (score 1):

I think the main point you are missing is that data cleaning is an empirical process. Text preprocessing may consist of removing stop words, punctuations, numericals, lowercasing, but if this adds to model's ability to learn and generalize remains to be seen through Cross Validation, i.e. feeding results of your peprocessing to model train and seeing if this generalizes to test well.

In general preproceeeing (stop words removal, etc) works well for Bag of Words models because it reduces data dimensionality because data in BOW is long and sparse (check out [Curse of dimensionality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curse_of_dimensionality) e.g. for possible theoretical foundations). The need for data preprocessing is diminished with word embeddings like word2vec or BERT.

In short, if you have any data preprocessing in mind, check if it helps your model to learn and generalize through properly constructed CV.

Comment: @rbb Does it answer your question? Was it helpful? Please consider https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers